# SSRS nested IIF statement not working correctly

Tags: reporting-services, nested

I have problem while using nested IIF in SSRS. I dont know what is wrong with the statement below:

```
=iif((Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value >=0.5) And (Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value <=2) ,"lime",
iif((Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value >=0) And (Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value <0.5) , "Gold",
iif((Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value >=2) And (Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value <=3) , "Gold",
iif((Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value >3) , "Red","Black"))))
```

It should return Lime when value is 1.63, but I am getting Gold color. Kindly, help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

I also tried Switch but the results are same:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value>=0.5 And Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value <=2, "lime",
Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value >=0 And Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value <0.5 , "Gold",
Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value >=2 And Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value <=3,"Gold",
Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value >3 ,"Red")
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but these both work fine for me. No issues.

Comment: Your expression is correct. Are you sure value of RM_Sieve70 is 1.63? Check your dataset query.

Comment: yes the value is 1.60 ,1.58 and sometimes 1.63 ..but the point is these all values are less than 2.0 so it should return lime . i have no clue why this is happening

Comment: As others have said, this should work fine assuming the value you are checking is actually numeric. If this is in a table I would suggest adding a new column and setting the expression to `=Fields!RM_Sieve70.Value = 1.63` and see if it returns `True` or `False`. If the results in this new column are not what you expected then it's time to check datatypes etc.